# Ehcache with Terracotta - Guidelines required

Tags: hibernate, maven, ehcache, terracotta

Im using maven, hibernate3, struts and spring in my application and have successfully used ehcache. Caching is done locally and now i want to go distributed. I'm not able to find a good tutorial where it's explained step by step how i would be able to go distributed with ehcache with terracotta.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://tech.puredanger.com/2008/06/17/distributed-ehcache-with-terracotta/ consider reading this..

Answer (score 0):

You should go with BigMemory because the older version of Terracotta is not supported anymore.

Start here:

http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.0/bigmemorymax/configuration/configuration